# Trying to pipe into Set-ADAccountExpiration

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm taking a list of email addresses and future leave dates from a database and trying to populate the account expiry date in AD.

`$ds` contains email and leave date.

```
foreach ($mail in $ds[0].rows) {
    $ms = $mail.mail;
    Get-ADUser -Filter {(emailaddress -eq $ms) -And (Enabled -eq $True)} |
        Set-ADAccountExpiration -Datetime $mail.leavedate
}
```

The `Get-ADUser` part is working fine but the problem is the `$mail.leavedate` is not available to the command, only the results from `Get-ADUser`.

I've tried using `$_$mail.leavedate` but this passes through empty results.

Perhaps I need to create a new object with the result from `Get-ADUser` and the leave date, I'm just not sure how to do that or how to then use a new object with the `Set-ADAccountExpiration` command.

Comment: This looks like it should work to me, specifically by using `$mail.leavedate` assuming that is a valid sub-property of `$ds[0].rows`. You might want to check that `$mail.leavedate` is actually the value you expect and that it can be converted to a datetime object which is what the `-datetime` parameter accepts as input.

Comment: Can you provide a sample value for `$mail.leavedate`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for this.  The leavedate is a datetime object.  The problem I'm having is actually I don't have permission to update the accounts yet, but while testing I tried to replace the set-adaccountexpiration command with write-host $mail.leavedate.  This resulted in an error. 
 write-host : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command...  This leads me to believe that it also wouldn't work with set-adaccountexpiration since the data piped through is from the getuser object.

Comment: Just realised the error is because the piped data has nowhere to go.  my bad!  Will have to test when I get permissions...

Comment: Code after a `|` can go onto another line, so the object in the pipeline does have somewhere to go. The object returned by `Get-ADUser` is piped to the next command and used by the param at position `0`. Which for `Set-ADAccountExpiration` is the `Identity` param.

Comment: Thanks James, that worked.